# The distclean command is not recognised

Tags: command-line

I try to run the `disctlean` command to clean the previous build and I keep getting this error: `'distclean' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Any solution please?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're working with a project set up with GNU autotools and you meant

```
make distclean
```

not just `distclean`, because it's a make target and not a separate command. Or depending on your setup you might need to run `gmake` or similar instead of just `make`.